# unable to use three20 iphone library

Tags: iphone, three20

Well I am a newbie, developing an app. I want to use library 320 to display a set of thumbnails generated from a specific image directory .

When user clicks on an image  a particular action shold take place.  Unable to understand how to implement this library due to poor documentation. Can any body suggest me a better tutorial or source or piece of code to understand this .

I googled it but the outcome was not profitable. 
Please enlighten me on this.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the TTCatalog example project that comes with the Three20 source, it shows a fairly standard implementation of photo thumbnails.

Barring that, you can check out the slowly growing Three20 documentation.

Articles and tutorials:
http://three20.info/

API documentation:
http://api.three20.info/